# Where have you used gSOAP?

Tags: soap, gsoap

Can you give examples how you used gSOAP and how well it was integrated in your existing architecture? Have you found development bottlenecks with gSOAP?

Answer (score 4):

We used gSOAP for a bunch of ARM clients to communicate with an AXIS Web Service server. Pros of gSOAP:

- very powerful, supports nearly all Web Service constructs
- easy to use, its abstraction of WS calls into functions removes all Web Service complexity to the programmer
- elegant interfaces in both C and C++

However, we ran into several development bottlenecks:

- when using custom datatypes like maps or sets, it takes quite some hacking to get the gSOAP compiler to handle them (marshal/unmarshalling). Especially bad with dynamic data structures.
- debugging is hard because of its intrinsic complex network, parsing and memory allocation parts. Do everything possible to stick with static memory allocation.
- the mailing list is alive, but developers are not very active on it. Simple questions can get answered quickly, but the toughest problems often go unanswered
- forget about optimization. Linking in gSOAP eats about 1MB of memory at runtime (-Os). Runtime performance is fine on our 32MB linux-based ARM board, but there really is little to do about optimization if you need it.

Answer (score 2):

We used gSOAP in a C++-based web server about 4 years back. Overall it worked fine. The only major issue was that the interface was in C and procedural (I understand it is difficult to design a good non-procedural interface). There may be a lot of repeated code while implementing the interface, for which you might have to use macros (we didn't explore the templates option too far then).

Answer (score 1):

We are using gSoap to deploy a web service onto an embedde linux device running an ARM MX processor.

Answer (score 1):

We are using gSOAP to consume a WCF based webservice from an application deployed on a linux device running on ARM processor. The experience is good to a large extent.

Answer (score 0):

We used gSOAP in a web server on ARM ARM9 400MHz device. 
gSOAP daemon connected to a database daemon through zeromq library, which is run on the same device.

It supports more than 1000 basic requests wich does not requre connection to database.

Disabling  support for multi-referenced SOAP option by the WITH_NOIDREF define helped to decrease serialization time about 4 times faster on big requests with large number of serialization nodes.